# JavaScript prototype is not copied

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

For some reason, my classes written in CoffeeScript do not copy the prototype.

Here's the exact code I'm using:

```
module.exports = class ListQueue
  constructor: ->
    @queue = []
    @queueIds =[]
    @currentId = 0

  # Adds the given element to the queue.
  # Returns the index of the element.
  add: (el) ->
    @queueIds.push @currentId
    @queue.push el
    @currentId++ # return @lastIndex, then increment

  shift: ->
    @queueIndexes.shift()
    @queue.shift()

  # Returns the index in the @queue array for the given id.
  queueIndex: (id) ->
    for queueIndex, i in queueIndexes
      if queueIndex is id
        return i
    undefined

  get: (id) ->
    index = @queueIndex id
    @queue[index]

  length: ->
    @queue.length

  remove: (id) ->
    index = @queueIndex id
    if index?
      @queueIds = @queueIds.slice index, index
      @queue = @queue.slice index, index
      true
    else
      false
```

This is the prototype of the class, as expected:

```
  { add: [Function],
  shift: [Function],
  queueIndex: [Function],
  get: [Function],
  length: [Function],
  remove: [Function] }
```

But this is weird: `new ListQueue` actually gives me this:

```
  { queue: [], queueIds: [], currentId: 0 }
```

I'm using Node.JS 0.8.7.

Comment: Maybe if you post some JavaScript someone can help you.

Comment: I don't know coffeescript, but could you provide the compiled JavaScript?

Comment: Your code should work. Can you post some code that demonstrates the absence of `.do` on a `new Test()`?

Comment: Sorry for the short question, I extended it by some actual code.

Answer (score 3):

The do function is actually there, if you execute

```
new Test().do()
```

you will get "test"

If you want intellisense type support, try adding a constructor first. It will create function variables, and bind them, like so:

```
this.LoadData = __bind(this.LoadData, this);
```

This will allow you to explicitly call them.

Comment: The problem is that `do` does not actually exist.

Comment: Define not exist? I ran the coffee code and was able to get it to call the do function.

Comment: The resulting object is completely empty, which means that the method also does not exist. The weird thing is that it works fine in the browser (!) but not locally for me on Node.